# Draw nice curved path along points

Tags: android, android-canvas

How do I draw a path along some defined points in a way so that the path is nicely curved and not necessary exactly touching the defined points, except the end points where the line must be ending at the exact points? I have tried with quadTo, but that gives me jagged connections between the quadTo end/start in some situations.

To illustrate what I want I have attached this example image: [image: example]

Thank you
Søren

Comment: see [this](http://www.antigrain.com/research/bezier_interpolation/)

Comment: and [here](https://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/) you have arithmetic solution, the previous link was geometric one, you can access the online interactive demo [here](https://www.particleincell.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/circles.svg)

Comment: the second approach is easier as you have the complete source code (in javascript)